# How to work with mouseover events in Siverlight when I have 2 mouseoverable objects in the same space?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a map (which is made of paths), and above this map, in another canvas, I have some elipses that I intend to use as buttons. I created their mouseover events, but when I tested just the harbor mouseover were triggered (before creating this harbors, the state mouseover worked well). How should I make them both work, in a way that when I mouseover a button that is inside a map, just this mouseover event is triggered?

**This is the XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Opacity="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="Pics">
            <Image Height="600" Width="800" Canvas.Top="0" Source="Layout_Brasil.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="StateButtons">
            <Path x:Name="PR" DataContext="PR" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Height="62.983" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF3060FF" Stroke="Black" Width="96.458" Opacity="0" Canvas.Left="288.399" Canvas.Top="422.459"/>
            <Path x:Name="SC" DataContext="SC" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="80.278" Height="52.48" Canvas.Left="298.823" Canvas.Top="471.681" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " Fill="#FF3060FF" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
            <Path x:Name="RS" DataContext="RS" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="119.469" Height="101.401" Canvas.Left="241.82" Canvas.Top="486.942" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="SP" DataContext="SP" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="133.368" Height="83.526" Canvas.Left="308.33" Canvas.Top="382.902" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="MS" DataContext="MS" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="107.488" Height="102.55" Canvas.Left="235.98" Canvas.Top="346.341" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0.01"/>
            <Path x:Name="RJ" DataContext="RJ" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="60.163" Height="40.418" Canvas.Left="427.091" Canvas.Top="397.632" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="ES" DataContext="ES" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="34.801" Height="52.446" Canvas.Left="470.421" Canvas.Top="356.008" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="MG" DataContext="MG" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="164.552" Height="128.429" Canvas.Left="338.339" Canvas.Top="304.022" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="GO" DataContext="GO" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="107.852" Height="103.661" Canvas.Left="307.997" Canvas.Top="278.051" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="DF" DataContext="DF" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="18.291" Height="11.789" Canvas.Left="378.156" Canvas.Top="321.553" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
            <Path x:Name="MT" DataContext="MT" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="167.277" Height="156.707" Canvas.Left="186.723" Canvas.Top="205.169" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="RO" DataContext="RO" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="104.209" Height="85.239" Canvas.Left="113.481" Canvas.Top="214.815" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="AC" DataContext="AC" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="108.027" Height="60.424" Canvas.Left="11.006" Canvas.Top="202.149" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="AM" DataContext="AM" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="254.824" Height="174.388" Canvas.Left="14.62" Canvas.Top="68.635" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="PA" DataContext="PA" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="187.286" Height="180.958" Canvas.Left="225.888" Canvas.Top="63.565" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="RR" DataContext="RR" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="88.245" Height="101.625" Canvas.Left="141.248" Canvas.Top="24.08" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="AP" DataContext="AP" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="74.189" Height="83.259" Canvas.Left="284.959" Canvas.Top="37.59" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="BA" DataContext="BA" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="136.864" Height="144.652" Canvas.Left="401.947" Canvas.Top="221.765" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="TO" DataContext="TO" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="75.971" Height="120.857" Canvas.Left="343.001" Canvas.Top="174.198" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="MA" DataContext="MA" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="101.017" Height="133.686" Canvas.Left="372.788" Canvas.Top="115.916" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="PI" DataContext="PI" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="83.894" Height="120.456" Canvas.Left="411.509" Canvas.Top="138.767" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="CE" DataContext="CE" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="62.211" Height="75.45" Canvas.Left="477.305" Canvas.Top="140.065" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="RN" DataContext="RN" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="54.818" Height="33.389" Canvas.Left="517.772" Canvas.Top="169.607" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z "UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="PB" DataContext="PB" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="59.445" Height="35.755" Canvas.Left="515.145" Canvas.Top="186.43" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z "UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="PE" DataContext="PE" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="97.953" Height="35.631" Canvas.Left="477.138" Canvas.Top="203.485" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="AL" DataContext="AL" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="46.743" Height="25.551" Canvas.Left="522.847" Canvas.Top="226.947" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path x:Name="SE" DataContext="SE" MouseEnter="MouseOverState" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveState" Width="30.537" Height="33.361" Canvas.Left="522.277" Canvas.Top="236.29" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3.83891" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="M ALOTOFSTUFF Z " UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="#FF286DFF" Opacity="0"/>
            <Image Height="600" Width="800" Opacity="0" Source="Layout_Brasil_Portos.png" Stretch="Fill" d:IsHidden="True"/>            
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Name="HarborButtons">
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="204" Canvas.Top="139"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="280" Canvas.Top="129"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="331" Canvas.Top="95"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="428" Canvas.Top="131"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="559" Canvas.Top="177"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="565" Canvas.Top="194"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="552" Canvas.Top="233"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="505" Canvas.Top="306"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="331" Canvas.Top="524"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="413" Canvas.Top="435"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="398" Canvas.Top="439"/>
            <Ellipse Fill="#FF286DFF" MouseEnter="MouseOverHarbor" MouseLeave="MouseLeaveHarbor" Stroke="Black" Height="14" Width="14" Canvas.Left="462" Canvas.Top="423"/>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
```

And **this is the .cs code behind:**

```
namespace WebPortos
{
    public partial class Brasil : UserControl
    {
        public Brasil()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MouseOverState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Path thisPath = (Path)sender;
            thisPath.Opacity = 0.25;
        }

        private void MouseLeaveState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Path thisPath = (Path)sender;
            thisPath.Opacity = 0;
        }

        private void MouseOverHarbor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse thisPath = (Ellipse)sender;
            thisPath.Opacity = 0.25;
        }

        private void MouseLeaveHarbor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse thisPath = (Ellipse)sender;
            thisPath.Opacity = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was already solved and I had no idea. It all worked all right when I came to work today ... maybe I just had to rebuild my project ... but the way I showed above works fine for that intention.

Comment: When I duplicated your original code the problem occurs whenever you enter and leave the overlapping harbour objects on top of states. Are you saying that you have not changed the above code at all and it now works properly?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, change your mouse event handlers to have a *MouseEventArgs e* instead of *RoutedEventArgs e*.

Then you can use this code to get a list of *all* elements under the mouse:

```
List<UIElement> list = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(null),
                                   LayoutRoot as UIElement) as List<UIElement>;
```

You can then add your own logic to see what is under the mouse and ensure all elements are highlighted correctly. e.g. this part will ensure that all states under harbours are highlighted:

```
private void MouseOverHarbor(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    List<UIElement> list = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(null),
                           LayoutRoot as UIElement) as List<UIElement>;
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (item is Path)
        {
            item.Opacity = 0.25;    // Set state opacity
        }
        else if (item is Ellipse)
        {
            item.Opacity = 0.25;    // Set harbour opacity
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It helped me, but I still have some problems with it. The mouseleave method doesn't work properly (which is almost the same as the mouseover above). I also added a boolean, that checks if there is an ellipse in the list (if it does, the path doesn't get highlighted). But, apparently, when a call to this method is made, it isn't possible to call this method from another object.

Comment: Hi there. The post was just meant to start you in the right direction. If you need further help, you can contact us through our website if you prefer, otherwise post more of your code and I will suggest fixes. In the case you mention it is probably better to retain a static list of the previous selected items and make the logic on MouseLeave smarter (e.g. it will turn off any items previously highlighted. I can't comment on "other object" problem without seeing your code. Thanks.